# Implementation of zero flag without zero flag in program status word

Tags: cpu-architecture

In a typical processor’s PSW, zero flag is not implemented, however, it has Carry, Sign, Parity, and Overflow flags. In this architecture how would a programmer implement JZ (jump on zero).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't implement JZ after any arbitrary instruction like `add reg, reg` if there is no zero flag, none of the other flags carry the same information.  e.g. 8-bit -128 + -128 overflows and carries to 0, but you can't distinguish that from -128 + -1 that overflows / carries to 127.  Or various other combinations that you can't distinguish even with the help of SF and PF.

That's *why* we have a Zero Flag in normal ISAs, including 8080 or x86 whose flags and mnemonics you're using.

---

Did you actually just want to emulate x86 `test eax,eax` / `jz` or ARM `cbz reg, target` (conditional-branch on a register being zero) to test a register and jump if it was zero?

Note that `0` is the only number unsigned-below 1, so you can cmp / jnc.  This looks like homework so I'm not going to spell it out more than that.

Or do what MIPS does, and provide an instruction like `beq $reg, $reg, target` that you can use to compare-and-branch on any pair of regs.  (MIPS doesn't have a PSW / FLAGS at all).  MIPS has an architectural zero register that always reads as zero, so you can always branch on any other register being zero with one machine instruction.

ARM Thumb, and AArch64, provide a limited version of that: `cbz` and `cbnz` that compare/branch on a single register being zero or non-zero, separate from the ARM flags register.

But really if you're going to have a FLAGS / PSW register at all, implement a zero flag.  That's one of the most basic useful things.  Although to be fair, a carry flag is even more critical.  If you could only have one flag, it would probably be carry because you can still test for zero efficiently.  Signed compares for greater or less are harder to emulate with SF and OF, though.